# Problems re-positioning Flex buttons

Tags: flash, apache-flex, builder

I have literally scavenged every resource I could find to determine a solution for the issue I have. Basically, I can't re-designate the x or y position of any of my buttons (through source or design). If any of you can suggest how I could solve this, I will appreciate this greatly. Thank you. :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:local="*" 
    frameRate="999" 
    creationComplete="init();"
    >
    <mx:Style source="Whistle.css"/>
    <!--local:whistle id="myWhistle"/-->
        <mx:Label text="=" width="13" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="15"/>
        <mx:Text text="{tempo_slider.value}" width="30"/>

    <mx:Button id="stop" icon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-stop.png')"
        click="{if (playPause.selected) {player.stop();playPause.selected=false;}}"/>
    <mx:Button id="playPause" width="40"

               click="{if (playPause.selected) player.play(); else player.pause();}"
               downIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-pause.png')" labelPlacement="top"
               overIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-start.png')"
               selectedDownIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-start.png')"
               selectedOverIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-pause.png')"
               selectedUpIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-pause.png')" toggle="true"
               upIcon="@Embed(source='../assets/media-playback-start.png')"/>
    <mx:Button id="loop" toggle="true"

        icon="@Embed(source='../assets/view-refresh.png')"
        change="{player.loop=loop.selected;}"/>

    <!--<mx:Label text="midiFileURL={midiFileURL}" />-->

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            //[Bindable]
            private var midiFileURL:String;
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import com.knet.Player;
            private var player:Player;
            private function init():void {
                midiFileURL=FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.midiFileURL;
                //midiFileURL="http://www.reveeveille.net/audio/gavotte_yves_menez_0.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/gavotte_yves_menez_0.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/bwv806b.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/gavotte_de_audiern.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/an_alarch.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/Another_Jig_Will_Do.mid";
                midiFileURL="../assets/bro_goz.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/derobee_de_guingamp.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/Evit_Farsal_waltz.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/mtsofmourne.mid";
                //midiFileURL="../assets/andro_traditionnel_09.mid";
                player=new Player(/*myWhistle,*/tempo_slider,  midiFileURL);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to reposition them?

Comment: anything. i tried shifting the x positions. and y. but no alterations.

Comment: design mode just positions them underneath each other automatically, (a pink dotted line shows) i want to edit it freeform

Comment: I neglected to notice this was using MX Application.  I bet @SamDeHaan nailed it.  The default layout is vertical: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/LayoutContainer.html#layout

Answer (score 0):

Either use layout="absolute" in the application tag, or put the buttons inside a canvas container and then position them using the x,y attributes.

When you don't use absolute or use controls like HBox VBox setting the x,y values don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not specify layout for an application then bi-default it is 'vertical'. so in "vertical" layout you can not place your component on desired location; to achieve this you need to specify the application layout as absolute, so it ll work.